# Showing the same basis in two nth dimensional vectorspace and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I am curious to know if theres a way of proving that the n-th dimensional spaces U and W have the same basis. That is, showing that a vector space as a subspace of itself is itself, by showing they have the same basis and same dimension.

Given U is an n-th dimensional subspace of an n-th dimensional vector space W. Im wondering if this information implies enough vector space properties to show they have the same basis vector(s).

Answer (score 0):

That is enough. Let $(e_i)_{i\leq n}$ be a basis of $U$ then each $e_i$ is in $W$ since $U\subset W$. Then $(e_i)_{i\leq n}$ is also a basis of $W$ because they remain linearly independent (the equation for linear independence remains the same whatever the vector space) and there are as many as the dimension of $W$.

You then have: $U=\text{Span} (e_1,...,e_n)=W$.

Comment: The part I'm confused about or maybe is vague to me... is how linear independence shows that the basis set of U is also the basis of W. But its clear to me that if they exist in U then they exist in W (but just because they exist in both does imply they are the basis for both or does it?)

Comment: Well, the property I am using is, a collection of $n$ linearly independent vectors of an $n$-th dimensional space $E$ is a basis of $E$. Linear independence is the same in $U$ and $W$ (write both equations to see for yourself), and the dimension is an hypothesis.

Comment: yes thanks, I didn't reply because commenting doesn't usually allow short comments.

Comment: It's okay, I just wanted to make sure you understood.

Comment: just a side question , does row equivalence ALSO imply they have the same number of rows? additional its other definitions

Comment: What do you mean by row equivalence? What rows? If we are talking about the matrix of the basis, then, since $U$ and $W$ share all their basis (because they are the same space), then the associated matrices have the same size ($n\times n$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76259/discussion-between-localplutonium-and-bill-oharan).